# Kubuntu 22.04.1 no GUI or plasma desktop on boot, just TTY

Tags: drivers, upgrade, kubuntu, 22.04, amd-graphics

To provide some background about the situation, this all started recently when I tried to update and/or reinstall my AMD drivers (for Radeon RX 560 card), but it wasn't able to finish completely. However, my system kept working as usual. As a possible fix, I also did the release upgrade from Focal to Jammy, but ever since I have only been able to use the TTYs as no desktop or GUI seems to function.

I tried a suggestion to use `kstart`, which returned

```
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Reinstalling as suggested didn't seem to work.

Other suggestions I found were `DISPLAY=:0 plasmashell`, which gives the same output as `kstart`, and `xhost +local:`, which returns

```
xhost: unable to open display ""
```

Moving back to the graphics drivers, I used the AMD site to get an installer script and, following the instructions, tried to use `amdgpu-install --vulkan=amdvlk,pro --opencl=rocr,legacy --opengl=mesa`, which fails at some point, and the simpler `amdgpu-install --usecase=graphics`, which fails at the same point, some error while building.

The below link contains the output of when I attempted to run the above commands (and more), including a log that one of the errors says to consult. All stitched together and manually typed because of the situation

https://pastebin.com/3Rh9hwgf

At this point I just want to log into my usual desktop again, all I can do is use my phone currently. I don't know if messing with the drivers is even necessesary to fix this situation but I thought it might be relevant. I'm relatively new to Ubuntu and Linux in general, please let me know what additional information may be needed and how I can obtain it.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. 
I have a laptop and I am using the Intel-integrated GPU. I don't have a full solution for this problem but by running `sudo apt install qt5dxcb-plugin` package, I was able to eliminate the plugin error part, I only get the `qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display`.
Perhaps, in your case, because you have an AMD GPU, it could work for you.